# Zend Framework routes not working

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I'm having a problem with my Zend Framework application. It was working just fine on my old server, but I've moved it to a new server and for some reason it's no longer working.

If I go to the site's address, I get the main page. But when I try any of the links, I get a 404 error from Apache itself--not from the Zend Framework error controller.

I just set this new server up, and it's likely I've forgotten something, but I have no idea what it is. I don't do a lot of server administrative work, so I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your apache httpd.conf need allow override:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I'd forgotten something, but it's been so bloody long since I've set up a new server that I'd totally forgotten. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check document root ways on new server, your **index.php** is in **public** folder ?